# Error in cross-compiling a C code--unknown type name '__syscall_slong_t'

Tags: c, ubuntu, makefile, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile a code with CodeSourcery Arm compiler and I receive this error: `CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/include/time.h:123:5: error: unknown type name '__syscall_slong_t'`

Do you know how to fix this error? 
I am using Ubuntu 12.04 OS.

This is my Makefile :
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6010932/
and this is what I have after "make" command:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6010923/

Comment: perhaps you need to `#define` for signed long type.Your toolchain does not have this definition.

Comment: Are you compiling x64 or x32.  I think you need to compile 32-bit.

Comment: Have a look at this thread [mailing lists sourceware](http://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2012-05/msg01292.html)

Comment: @Dayalrai I have previously done the same thing without any problem but I had to format my Ubuntu due to some reasons. Now that I have installed CodeSourcery it is not working as it used to.

Comment: @Jim can you please explain a little more? I am not and I guess you might be right! I remember sth like that not sure how to do it btw!

Comment: however the cross-compiler compiles a normal C program correctly ( with a warning though) `/research/jalal/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc hello.c ` will give me 
`cc1: warning: include location "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu" is unsafe for cross-compilation [-Wpoison-system-directories]` and I have 
`$ ls
a.out  hello.c` in my directory.

Comment: gcc -m32  or gcc -m64

Comment: Basically, some or all of your headers mismatch the target arch you're trying to compile for.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that -m32 to your CFLAGS entry.

Comment: This is for *x86*, not **ARM**? [R](http://stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r) comment about the mis-match is causing this confusion.  Header files for the **host** PC are being used to compile the **target** source code.  New compilers have `-sysroot`; we don't have the CodeSourcery `gcc` version, so it is hard to give advice.

Comment: That makes sense.  It's at least possible.

Comment: well, let me know what I need to copy/paste for you to be able to assist me. I yet haven't found a clear solution and that -m32 isn't recognized by compiler @artlessnoise

Comment: @MonaJalal I think you should be using the Include files that come with the codesourcery package. According to your Makefile, it doesn't look like you are doing that. You may be trying to build with Ubuntu's ordinary gcc includes, which would probably be a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to patch typesizes.h to match recent core changes, check this thread: http://sourceware.org/ml/libc-ports/2012-05/msg00095.html